# How can I pass form values off to an asp script without actually calling it from the form action?

Tags: css, forms, redirect, iframe, asp-classic

Here's what I am trying to do.  I have a page that uses CSS to show/hide different content divs.  One of the divs is a form that submits a record to a database.  After clicking "Submit" I do not want to redirect back to the default page content, which is what would happen by calling the script in the form action and using a simple response.redirect at the end of the ASP script.  Instead I want to pass the form info off to the ASP script in an iframe (or some other way) and then just clear the form.  This way the user can go ahead and enter another incident in the form without having to click an "Add Incident" button again in the navigation to show the hidden form div (which is how it loads the default page if I were to redirect back).

I see a couple of ways to handle this:
- As I mentioned above, the form data is sent off to the ASP in an iframe or some such thing.
- I call the ASP script as normal, but when doing the response.redirect to default.asp, somehow also tell the page to display the form div instead of the default content

In either case, I'm not sure exactly how I would do this.  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, what you want to do is not to post to iframe, but to use ajax with jquery. Rough outline would be something like this:

```
$(function () { 
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'submit.asp',
        data: 'input1=' + escape($.trim($('#input1').val())),
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data) {
            // clear the form
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Assuming I know absolutely nothing about AJAX...which I don't...where would I find a good primer/example of what I'm trying to do? Thanks for the above, but I have no idea what I'm looking at! This is the form data I'm posting: incidentTime=14%3A15&incidentDate=4%2F29%2F2014&eventName=Demo+Event&demAge=21&demGender=F&incidentLocation=Medical+Tent&incidentType=Allergic+Reaction&incidentDisposition=BLS+Ground+Transport

Comment: I actually found something really good here: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-Pass-Data-Values-from-one-page-to-another-using-jQuery.aspx   I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: In a few words, Ajax is technology that provides asynchronous request, so the form is submitted without reloading.  
In code above, if you have one form, leave code ('form'), and if you have more and form ID is form1, replace ('form') with ('#form1') don't forget the hash tag.

Comment: replace submit.asp with the asp page that processes submission;  
replace 'input1=' + escape($.trim($('#input1').val())), with the field IDs you submit:
'input1=' + escape($.trim($('#input1').val())) + '&input2=' + escape($.trim($('#input2').val())),  
as for clearing the form, it's some basic JS, ask if you need help.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Ajax to handle this scenario. With Javascript you can collect the form data and then make an ajax call when the user clicks your submit button.

Comment: Would be more useful if the answer was padded out with a quick example.